# Accessing RiotJS tag contents for multiple instance mounts

Tags: riot.js

I have an odd situation I don't know to resolve. Mounting the tag on a once off basis works fine. However, when I mount more than one copy of a tag in this manner:

**HTML:**

```
   <div class="o-container o-container--medium">
     <div class="o-grid o-grid--small-full o-grid--medium-full o-grid--large-full">
       <div id="crd-demo-1" class="o-grid__cell">

     <rg-card shadow="highest">
     My additional <b>content</b> here. <rg-badge style="success">This works!</rg-badge><br /><br />
     </rg-card>

   </div>
   <div id="crd-demo-2" class="o-grid__cell">

     <rg-card shadow="high">
       My additional <b>content</b> here. Other <b>RiotGear2</b> can also be used inside your card.
       <rg-badge style="brand">This works too!</rg-badge><br /><br />
     </rg-card>
   </div>
 </div>
```

Then I mount as follows:

```
          var tags = riot.mount("div#crd-demo-1","rg-card", {
    // omitted for clarity
          });

          var tags = riot.mount("div#crd-demo-2","rg-card", {
// omitted for clarity
          });
```

When I look at this.root._innerHTML I don't get the tag contents, but rather the parent declaration (**<rg-card ...>**) PLUS the contents. So it nests the tag within itself.

I know It's how I'm mounting the tag to provide different options for each one. Any suggestions on how to get around this warmly welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was solved for me on the RiotJS Github issues.

Here's the [link](https://github.com/riot/riot/issues/2287).

**Summary**

```
<div data-is="rg-card" .... >
   ... content
</div>
```